# Why is a constructor necessary in a const member struct?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a code similar to this:

```cpp
class AClass {
public:
  struct AStruct { };

  AClass(){}

private:
  const AStruct m_struct;
};

int main() {
  AClass a;
}
```

It throws this compilation error (with [Clang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) [LLVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM) version 5.1):

```cpp
error: constructor for 'AClass' must explicitly initialize 
       the const member 'm_struct'
```

If I specify a C++11 default constructor for `struct AStruct`, I get the same error:

```cpp
  struct AStruct {
    AStruct() = default;
  };
```

However, this is solved by writing a constructor with an empty body:

```cpp
  struct AStruct {
    AStruct(){}  // fixed
  };
```

Why do I need to specify an empty constructor? Isn't it automatically created with public access for structs?

Why does not the C++11 default constructor solve the problem?

Comment: Your use of `AStruct` and `AClass` is incredibly confusing, especially since both are classes. Can't you come up with better names?

Comment: Here is a [sscce version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/178ee740e3b6a14f).

Comment: You don't *have to* provide a default constructor, value initializing the `const` member is sufficient - http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa3bcb77ce7b04eb

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From §8.5 [dcl.init]/7:

> If a program calls for the default initialization of an object of a const-qualified type T, T shall be a class type with a user-provided default constructor.

The default constructor of `AClass` default-initializes the `const` member (see below), so that member must have a user-provided default constructor. Using `= default` does not result in a user-provided default constructor, as can be seen in §8.4.2 [dcl.fct.def.default]/4:

> A function is user-provided if it is user-declared and not explicitly defaulted or
> deleted on its first declaration.

---

The member is default-initialized per §12.6.2 [class.base.init]/8:

> In a non-delegating constructor, if a given non-static data member or base class is not designated by a mem-initializer-id (including the case where there is no mem-initializer-list because the constructor has no ctor-initializer) and the entity is not a virtual base class of an abstract class (10.4), then
>
> — if the entity is a non-static data member that has a brace-or-equal-initializer , the entity is initialized as specified in 8.5;
> — otherwise, if the entity is an anonymous union or a variant member (9.5), no initialization is performed;
> — **otherwise, the entity is default-initialized (8.5).**

Comment: @chris I use G++-4.8. There is no error. And I can even call a const method of `struct A` with no error. So, is this problem clang specific?

Comment: [Even worse](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b7b4fd8fefc3fa5) this code actually does something (and useful), yet we get a compiler error.  @PengZhang G++4.8 is violating the standard here, not clang.

Comment: @Casey [Wrong issue number](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#253).

Comment: @chris, To lend more weight to the quirk, if the `=default` is defined outside the class declaration, then that is seen as a user defined constructor, and compiles (8.4.2/5) [in the sample, `a` fails, `b` compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d06bb96b49b1f5c)

Comment: @Niall, I actually took care of that one :) *A function is user-provided if it is user-declared and not explicitly defaulted or deleted __on its first declaration__.*

Answer (score 19):

Stolen from @chris's answer we have this paragraph: §8.5 [dcl.init]/7:

> If a program calls for the default initialization of an object of a const-qualified type T, T shall be a class type with a user-provided default constructor.

We can then construct a completely ridiculous case that illustrates this restriction:

```
struct Foo {};
int main() {
  const Foo f;
}
```

which fails to compile in clang, as the standard dictates.  Your code is simply this, but as a member variable of another class/struct.

We can even do this:

```
struct Foo {int x = 3;};
int main() {
  const Foo f;
}
```

where all the data is obviously initialized.  This last example convinces me that this is a defect in the standard.

The thought was probably something to do with POD types being uninitialized and `const`, but the wording blocks code that is unrelated.  Default constructors in modern C++ are often more than good enough, and forcing `Foo(){}` is poor form.